# Simulate high dimension multivariate normal data in R

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to simulate high dimension multivariate normal data in R with n = 100, and p = 400 (two different groups of variables with some correlations). Below are my codes:

```
## load library MASS
library(MASS)

## sample size set to n = 100
sample_size <- 100      

## I try to simulate two different groups of variables for each with 200 variables                  
sample_meanvector <- c(runif(200,0,1), runif(200,6,8))

## covariance matrix, some variables set to be correlated
sample_covariance_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = 400, ncol = 400)
diag(sample_covariance_matrix) <- 1
set.seed(666)
sample_covariance_matrix[lower.tri(sample_covariance_matrix)] <- runif(79800, 0.00001, 0.2)
sample_covariance_matrix[lower.tri(sample_covariance_matrix)][sample(1:79800, 10000)] <- runif(10000, 0.6, 0.9)

## make the matrix symmetric
sample_covariance_matrix[upper.tri(sample_covariance_matrix)]<-t(sample_covariance_matrix)[upper.tri(sample_covariance_matrix)]

## create multivariate normal distribution
sample_distribution <- mvrnorm(n = sample_size,
                               mu = sample_meanvector,
                               Sigma = sample_covariance_matrix)
```

However, every time I run this mvrnorm function, I got the error:

> Error in mvrnorm(n = sample_size, mu = sample_meanvector, Sigma =
> sample_covariance_matrix) :    'Sigma' is not positive definite

I have two questions:

1. Why do I have this error?
2. How can I edit my codes to simulate the high dimension multivariate normal data following my idea mentioned above?

Thanks much!

Comment: Do this before running `mvrnorm()`: `sample_covariance_matrix <- psych::cor.smooth(sample_covariance_matrix)`

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Hi Dave, thanks for the suggestion. This function does help to fix this error, however, after running this one, the range of my correlation setting is changed to (-0.05, 0.32), it's not expected. I still want to keep the high correlation between some of the variables. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You could also try `Matrix::nearPD()` or `sfsmisc::posdefify()`

Comment: This seems like a hard problem.  You want to construct a high-dimensional positive definite matrix with a bimodal distribution of entries (about 7/8 between 0 and 0.2 and 1/8 between 0.6 and 0.9).  You might ask on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), as all the methods suggested so far to enforce positive definiteness also destroy the high correlation values. (Intuitively, if we have points A, B, C, it's hard for two pairs (A-B, A-C) to have low correlation and the third (B-C) to have high correlation ...

Comment: @BenBolker Hi Ben, thanks for the suggestion, that's very helpful. I think my covariance matrix setting might be too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that can generate a highly correlated matrix :

```
library(MASS)
library(Matrix)

sample_size <- 100      
sample_meanvector <- c(runif(200,0,1), runif(200,6,8))
sample_covariance_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = 400, ncol = 400)
diag(sample_covariance_matrix) <- 1
set.seed(666)

mat_Sim <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 400, ncol = 400)
U <- runif(n = 400) * 0.5

for(i in 1 : 400)
{
  if(i <= 350)
  {
    U_Star <- pmin(U + 0.25 * runif(n = 400), 0.99999)
    
  }else
  {
    U_Star <- pmin(pmax(U + sample(c(-1, 1), size = 400, replace = TRUE) * runif(n = 400), 0.00001), 0.99999)
  }
  
  mat_Sim[, i] <- qnorm(U_Star)  
}

cor_Mat <- cor(mat_Sim)
sample_covariance_matrix <- cor_Mat * 200

## create multivariate normal distribution
sample_distribution <- mvrnorm(n = sample_size,
                               mu = sample_meanvector,
                               Sigma = sample_covariance_matrix)

image(cor_Mat)
```

with 7 / 8 of the matrix correlated between 0.6 and 0.8 and 1 / 8 of the matrix correlated between 0 and 0.3. [image: heatmap of correlation matrix]

Comment: can you explain the concept behind your answer?

Comment: Yeah, it is pretty straightforward. I started from uniform numers (i. e. the variable U). Afterwards, I generated some modified uniform numbers (i. e. U_Star) which is a perturbation of the variable U. Using U_Star, I generated numbers from a standard normal distribution. Since there is a common "U" for all the simulated columns of the matrix mat_Sim, it generates a set of correlated normal distribution. With this construction, we are guaranteed that the correlation matrix will be high for i <= 350 and low for i > 350.

Comment: You can also modify the different parameters used to simulate the U_Star (e. g. the 0.25 coefficient) to increase or decrease the correlation in the matrix cor_Mat

Comment: So we end up with something with some block structure?

Comment: Yeah, we can generate the block structure we want with this approach

Comment: Thanks, @EmmanuelHamel. The answer is impressive.

Comment: I am happy that this answer is helping you. For your information, we could easily generalize this method to generate a correlation matrix with an arbitrary number of blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following code :

```
library(MASS)
library(Matrix)

sample_size <- 100      
sample_meanvector <- c(runif(200,0,1), runif(200,6,8))
sample_covariance_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = 400, ncol = 400)
diag(sample_covariance_matrix) <- 1
set.seed(666)
sample_covariance_matrix[lower.tri(sample_covariance_matrix)] <- runif(79800, 0.00001, 0.2)
sample_covariance_matrix[lower.tri(sample_covariance_matrix)][sample(1:79800, 10000)] <- runif(10000, 0.6, 0.9)
sample_covariance_matrix[upper.tri(sample_covariance_matrix)]<-t(sample_covariance_matrix)[upper.tri(sample_covariance_matrix)]
sample_covariance_matrix_Near_PD <- nearPD(sample_covariance_matrix)$mat


## create multivariate normal distribution
sample_distribution <- mvrnorm(n = sample_size,
                               mu = sample_meanvector,
                               Sigma = sample_covariance_matrix_Near_PD)
```

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, thanks for the codes. However, this method will destroy the high correlation setting in the covariance matrix.

Comment: Do you need this particular setting or you just need a highly correlation matrix?

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, I just need some high correlation matrix in my simulation setting. 0.6 - 0.9 is just an example here. Thanks!

Comment: And I found an acceptable way to do the simulation based on this answer. For my previous codes, I put high correlation and low correlation in one covariance matrix, and the high correlation is destroyed by "find close positive matrix" function. But, if I put high correlation and low correlation in two separate covariance matrices and simulate them separately, then some high correlations still exist.

Comment: It seems like a good approach!

Answer (score 0):

In my question, I put high correlations and low correlations in the same covariance matrix. And then the high correlations are destroyed by the "find close positive definite matrix" function. However, when I simulate these two parts separately, the high correlation won't be affected much. Below are my updated codes:

```
# load library MASS
library(MASS)
sample_size <- 100

##### Saperate high and low correlation part ####
### High correlation ###
sample_mean_high <- c(runif(50, -1 , 1))
sample_cov_high <- matrix(0, nrow = 50, ncol = 50)
diag(sample_cov_high) <- 1
sample_cov_high[lower.tri(sample_cov_high)] <- runif(1225, 0.6, 0.9)
sample_cov_high[upper.tri(sample_cov_high)] <- t(sample_cov_high[lower.tri(sample_cov_high)])
sample_cov_high <- sfsmisc::posdefify(sample_cov_high)
# create multivariate normal distribution
sample_dist_high <- mvrnorm(n = sample_size, mu = sample_mean_high, Sigma = sample_cov_high)

### Low correlation ###
sample_mean_low <- c(runif(350, -1 , 1))
sample_cov_low <- matrix(0, nrow = 350, ncol = 350)
diag(sample_cov_low) <- 1
sample_cov_low[lower.tri(sample_cov_low)] <- runif(61075, -0.5, 0.5)
sample_cov_low[upper.tri(sample_cov_low)] <- t(sample_cov_low[lower.tri(sample_cov_low)])
sample_cov_low <- sfsmisc::posdefify(sample_cov_low)
# create multivariate normal distribution
sample_dist_low <- mvrnorm(n = sample_size, mu = sample_mean_low, Sigma = sample_cov_low)

### Check correlation ###
cor_high <- cor(sample_dist_high)
hist(cor_high[lower.tri(cor_high)])
cor_low <- cor(sample_dist_low)
hist(cor_low[lower.tri(cor_low)])
cor_between <- cor(sample_dist_high, sample_dist_low)
hist(cor_between[lower.tri(cor_between)])
```

Then I get the correlation I expected.